# What is the correct way to write routes in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css

There are some routes present in my application. I want to render the feed details in the same parent route rather than opening a different/rendering a new URL. The catch is, there is also a Search page that I want to render in the parent route, but the route is not working as I expected it to.

**What I tried:** Used React outlook hook to render in the parent element, which is working. But the search routes are not rendering as I want them to, only the link is getting changed.

What should I do to solve this?

I have made a design prototype of my application. Upon request, I would include it.

**APP.jsx**

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="*" element={<Home user={user} />}/>
</Routes>
```

**HOME.jsx**

```
<>
        <Navbar user={user}/>

        {/*Routes*/}
        <>
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path={"/"} element={<Feed/>}>
                        <Route path={"pin/:pinId"} element={<PinDetails user={user}/>}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path={"/pin/:pinId"} element={<PinDetails user={user}/>}/>

                    <Route path={"search"} element={<Search/>}>

                    </Route>
                    <Route path={"/login"} element={<div>Login component</div>}/>
                    <Route path={"/user/profile/:userId"} element={<UserProfile user={user}/>}/>
                    <Route path={"/wishlist/user/:userId"} element={<Wishlist user={user}/>}/>
                    <Route path={"/categories"} element={<Categories user={user}/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </Suspense>
        </>

    </>
```

Comment: Can you please include your codebase (preferably in the form of a GitHub repo) in order to understand the problem better?

Comment: @Ankit_M okay, i am adding

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by _I want to render the feed details in the same parent route rather than opening a different/rendering a new URL_?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes, My end goal is rather than navigating to a different page/ loading a new tab my post details should render in the same tab, where the rendered post details would slide in from the left. Displaying all the data that is necessary. After that A back button will be there and upon clicking on it the post details will slide back to right hiding the route, navigating to the previous parent route.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to make modal routes, where one route renders on top of another route. You can check out this [tutorial](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/modal) from react router on how to implement that.

Comment: Im sorry, but my feed details almost work like this. Is there any difference between my approach and this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I solve it using the latest version. You can achieve it, through the creation of a Layout component.

First create a [createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#createbrowserrouter), an object containing all your routes. Create a Parent,containing all desired children routes E.g:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Dog />,
      },
      {
        path: "/cat",
        element: <Cat />,
      },
      {
        path: "/dog",
        element: <Dog />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

On your Layout component add an `<Outlet />`, add `<RouterProvider router={router}/>` on your main file. Then add `<Link to="path"/>` where you need redirects. This is going to trigger rendering only on children routes, not on the layout component. You can check my code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-sanderson-gd3rl1).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I have tried to implement a similar approach using JSX elements. But my problem is not solved yet! Can you tell me which approach is best suited for this?

Comment: Also, i should mention there is 2 types of children like that. I would like to render under the same parent, more like stacking them one above the other.  One thing to note is that only one child will get rendered at a like, for example: either search page is rendered, or post details will be rendered.

Comment: I think this [video](https://youtu.be/-t7PgfHHHOw) will suit your case, please provide me a feedback.

Comment: yes, i checked the video you shared. It seems in that video, he created his own solution to render children which basically react is providing in the latest version already. But his approach was good! i will try it!